# convert matlab code to C#

Tags: c#

I have converted a simple Matlab code to C#.
But when I try to run it this warning appears:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in Matlabdl_dll.exe Additional information: The type
>   initializer for 'MatlabdlNative.Edge' threw an exception."

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Matlabdl_dll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MatlabdlNative.Edge Ma = new MatlabdlNative.Edge();
            DialogResult dr;
            dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Ma.Canny_fun(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full dump of the exception.

Comment: The problem happens when initializing `MatlabdlNative.Edge`, so is that a class you wrote?

Comment: This indicates a problem with `MatlabdlNative.Edge` class constructor (or other initialization), but you don't show the code for that.